# Can I close an AIR Application through Worker?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, worker

I have an application made in AIR that uses Worker object. Now, I need close my application through it, but I don't know how to do this...

Here's what I've tried:

- `NativeApplication.nativeApplication.exit();` exits Worker, not Application
- `System.exit(0);` not work in AIR, only FP Debugger
- `fscommand('quit');` not work in AIR, only FP
- `NativeApplication.nativeApplication.openedWindows[i].close();` in for, openedWindows.length returns '0'
- `WorkerDomain.current.listWorkers[i].terminate();` in for, terminate() don't work when 'isPrimordial' is true and the current Worker is a background Worker.

How can I exit my application through a background Worker?

**Example code:**

```
package {

    import flash.desktop.NativeApplication;
    import flash.system.fscommand;
    import flash.system.System;
    import flash.system.Worker;
    import flash.system.WorkerDomain;

    public class Main extends Sprite {

        private var _worker:Worker;

        public function Main() {

            if(Worker.current.isPrimordial) {
                _worker = WorkerDomain.current.createWorker(this.loaderInfo.bytes, true);
                _worker.start();
                trace("create worker");
            }
            else {
                trace("Worker started, lets close app!");
                //NativeApplication.nativeApplication.exit();
                //System.exit(0);
                //fscommand("quit");
                //NativeApplication.nativeApplication.openedWindows.length;
                //WorkerDomain.current.listWorkers[0].terminate();
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: As a general test, does `NativeApplication.nativeApplication.exit()` exit the application when you call it from the primordial Worker instance?

Comment: @Sly_cardinal, when I execute this code, works from de primordial... But I need call it from the background Worker. :/

Answer (score 1):

Though I haven't done this before, perhaps this would be a good way to implement this:

When you create your worker, listen for the TERMIANTED state change event, which will be dispatched when you terminate the worker (I"m not sure if doing nativeapplication.exit triggers this event, or if you have to explicitly call the `terminate()` method):

```
_worker = WorkerDomain.current.createWorker(this.loaderInfo.bytes, true);
_worker.addEventListener(WorkerState.TERMINATED, workerFinished, false, 0, true);
_worker.start();
```

Then, in that handler, exit the application:

```
private function workerFinished(e:Event):void {
    NativeApplication.nativeApplication.exit();
}
```

Comment: Another option you could try is passing a reference of the primordial to the worker using `setSharedProperty`, then using that reference to terminate/exit the primordial

Comment: I've tried `setSharedProperty`, but the same error of `WorkerDomain.current.listWorkers[0].terminate()` occurs... Your answer is great, but it's not for me. My idea is use the Worker to know when my application crashes, using other thread I can do this. But if the application crashes the primordial Worker will not listen the event.